# Finding the closest value in a Python dictionary and returning its key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a value

```
value = 0.04532
```

Also, a dictionary similar to this

```
{'1': 0.02827, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.09827, '4': 0.04533}
```

I want to simply return the key of the value in the dictionary that is closest to my original value, `4` in this case

I found an older post that does something like this

```
newValue = value
answer = min(dict.items(), key=lambda (_, value): abs(value - newValue))
```

This returns the tuple `('4', 0.04533)` and I just want the key (as an int).
Furthermore, I'm having trouble understanding what that code is doing exactly.

Is there a cleaner way to get this done?

Comment: Your title says you want the key, but the question says you want the value. Which is it?

Comment: Read the docs and play around in a Python shell to see what `abs(...)` does, what `dict.items()` (or better `list(dict.items())`) does and so on. The shown way to do this is clean and clever. You just have to extract the first item from the returned tuple and the convert it to an `int` using `int`.

Comment: @yodish, Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.11, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use sequence unpacking to unpack your `tuple` result:

```
value = 0.04532
d = {'1': 0.02827, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.09827, '4': 0.04533}

res_key, res_val = min(d.items(), key=lambda x: abs(value - x[1]))

print(res_key, res_val, sep=', ')

4, 0.04533
```

Half the problem appears to be in your choice of variables. Make sure you don't shadow class names, e.g. call your dictionary `d`, not `dict`. Likewise, don't name an argument of your `lambda` the same as a variable you've already defined.

Otherwise, the logic via `min` works as follows:

1. Take each tuple extracted from `d.items`, i.e. key-value pairs.
2. Apply the function `lambda x: abs(value - x[1])` to each tuple, i.e. calculate the absolute difference versus `value`.
3. Calculate the minimum result from the `lambda` function and return the argument supplied, in this case a *single* `tuple` from `d.items`.

Note [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) removes tuple parameter unpacking from Python 3.x, which is why we must explicitly extract the first value via `x[1]` in our `lambda`.

Answer (score 4):

`dict.items` gives you the (key, value) pairs of the dictionary.

```
>>> d = {'1': 0.02827, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.09827, '4': 0.04533}
>>> d.items()
dict_items([('1', 0.02827), ('3', 0.09827), ('2', 0.0), ('4', 0.04533)])
```

The return value is iterable and therefore can be passed to `min`.

`min` also takes a keyword argument `key` which has to be a callable (usually a function). It is the criterion by which `min` evaluates the elements from its first argument in order to find the minimum.

Here is a much simpler example. Suppose we need to find the shortest list within a list of lists.

```
>>> lists = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [5]]
>>> min(lists, key=len)
[5]
```

`min` iterates over `lists`, calls `len(sublist)` for every `sublist` in `lists` and returns the element where `len(sublist)` was minimal.

Examining, the proposed solution,

```
lambda (_, value): abs(value - newValue)
```

is an (anonymous) function (using [Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) which no longer works in Python 3) supposed to take an item, a (key, value) pair, and return `abs(value - newValue)`, which measures how close `value` is to `newValue`.

If the `lambda` confuses you, here's how you would write that `key` function in Python 3 as a normal function.

```
>>> def criterion(dict_item):
...     key, value = dict_item # unpack
...     return abs(value - newValue)
```

You can now issue

```
>>> newValue = 0.04532
>>> d = {'1': 0.02827, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.09827, '4': 0.04533}
>>> 
>>> min(d.items(), key=criterion)
('4', 0.04533)
```

If you want just the key as an integer, get it from index `0` and turn it into an `int`.

```
>>> int(min(d.items(), key=criterion)[0])
4
```

Finally, don't use the variable name `dict`, that name should be reserved for the builtin dictionary type.

Comment: I appreciate the explanations, definitely helpful!

Answer (score 3):

That code you referenced is simply looping through the key value pairs in the dictionary, computing the differences with your expected value and returning the minimum key value pair.

To just obtain the value, you can simply do this:

```
answer = min(dict.items(), key=lambda (_, value): abs(value - newValue))[1]
```

- note the indexing above as [1]

Are you sure you want it as an int type, it'll round down to the nearest integer

I would suggest just wrapping the statement above with a float()

Comment: The keys are whole numbers, those are what I needed to return as ints (I updated my question). Thanks!